# Background color & Background  image. Приоритеты?

Tags: html, css

В общем, цвет заливает картинку. А задача стоит наоборот - чтоб картинка была сначала, а когда она заканчивается, уже идет цвет.  
Либо подскажите, как ВЕРХНЮЮ часть рамки сделать картинкой? Заранее спасибо.

```
#body_in{
    outline:1px solid #C30;
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#e3bba5;
    background-image: url(../img/border_top.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

[Вот код](http://jsfiddle.net/86f5k592/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background: url(../img/border_top.png) no-repeat, #e3bba5;
```

Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Да.я прогнал.я уже пробовал ету тему...вообщем проблема была в цвете))))картинка и бг кол одним цветом-поэтому я ничегго не видел)

Comment: @Дмитрий Клименко, эта запись равносильна той, что дана в качестве примере внутри вопроса.